# How to create special words

Tags: c++

I'm trying to build a templat-class A and call its default constructor via a special word "NONE.
consider I have:

```
template<class T>
class A {
public:
    A():_val(0);
    A(T val):_val(val);
private:
    int _val;
}
```

and I want to be able to write

```
A<int> x = None;
```

which will call A();

I was thinking maybe I can use some sort of typedef, but I don't know how

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could provide a dummy type and a constructor that takes that type and does the equivalent of default constructing an instance. For example,

```
struct None_t {};

constexpr None_t None{}; // const None_t None = {}; in C++03

template<class T>
class A {
public:
    A() : _val() {};
    A(None_t) : A() {} // A(None_t) : _val() {} in C++03
    A(T val) : _val(val) {}
private:
    T _val;
};

int main()
{
   A<int> x = None;
}
```

Note I changed `_val` to from `int` to `T`, since otherwise the template doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 2):

The usual way would be to create a tag class, in this case `none_type` and have a constexpr (or static const) model of it available.

```
struct none_type {};
constexpr auto none = none_type {};

template<class T>
class A {
public:

    A():_val(0) {};

    A(none_type) : A() {};

    A(int val):_val(val) {};
private:
    int _val;
};

int main()
{
    A<int> a = none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'd use it but I'm constricted to C++98. Good to know about those new things anyway

Comment: Then make 'none' static const instead. In this scenario it has the same effect.